a basic question on random process
I am currently studying the infimum of a random process, however, it seems we can study it according to its supremum, but I am not sure my naive thought was correct or not. Speficially,
consider random function $$S(x_i):=\sum a_i x_i$$ where $a_i$ are iid random variables $1+w_i$, $w_i$ is standard gaussian $N(0,1)$, and $x_i\in[0,1]$, $\forall i\in[n]$. In other words, $T:=[0,1]$ is the index set of random process $S$.
My question is whether below formula is correct.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\inf_{\forall i, x_i\in[0,1]} S-\mathbb ES&=-\sup_{\forall i, x_i\in[0,1]} (\mathbb ES-S)\\
&\underbrace{=}_{S-\mathbb ES{=}\mathbb ES-S,\text{ in distribution}} -\sup_{\forall i, x_i\in[0,1]}(S-\mathbb ES)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In above, the key step I used would be $S-\mathbb ES=\mathbb E S-S$ in distribution. This is because $S-\mathbb ES=\sum_i a_i x_i-\sum x_i=\sum_i w_i x_i$ which is a centered gaussian whose variance is $\sum x_i^2$, and its distribution is symmetric. Thus I conclude that $$\sup_{\forall i, x_i\in[0,1]}(S-\mathbb ES)=\sup_{\forall i, x_i\in[0,1]}(\mathbb ES-S)$$
Would this be correct?
Another question: if we change $w_i$ from being $N(0,1)$ to Randemacher variable that takes value $1$ with probability $1-p$ and $-1$ with probability $p$, would above deduction still be correct? I think it is not, because $S-\mathbb ES$ is no longer symmetric (if I am correct), then how to deal with infimum of this function?
